# Extracting Macros in a Word Document to a text file from c#

Tags: c#, vba, ms-word

I need to extract all VBA code from a Word 2007 document in c# without using office automation.

What I have done so far is to open the Word document as a structured storage file in c#, and I receive a list of the following streams:

```
Macros
 VBA
   dir ( stream ) 
   Module1 ( stream )  
   ThisDocument ( stream )   
  _VBA_PROJECT_ ( stream )
  ....
```

I gather that the source is stored in one of those streams, but I have no idea how to parse them.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

Probably the documentation of the VBA file format will help you. You can download it for free from Microsoft:

> **[[MS-OVBA]: Office VBA File Format Structure Specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc313094%28office.12%29.aspx)**